# selecting a specific row using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

Scenario is that i have to select specific string variable and at the same time i have to click on the checkbox on the same row using xpath? Is this possible?

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<div class="ui-grid-canvas">
<div ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}">
    <div role="row" ui-grid-row="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell cell-contents ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-005E" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader, 'grid-cell-selected':row.entity.isChecked }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1554942178836-0-uiGrid-005E-cell">
            <wcl-task-manager-checked-row row-item="row.entity" handle-row-check="handleRowCheck(row.entity)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
                <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents cell-contents-align-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rowItem.isChecked" ng-change="toggleCheck(rowItem)" ng-disabled="disableCheckBoxForIWF(rowItem)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
                </div>
            </wcl-task-manager-checked-row>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell cell-contents ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-005F" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader, 'grid-cell-selected':row.entity.isChecked }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1554942178836-0-uiGrid-005F-cell">

        <wcl-task-manager-link-row row-item="row.entity" config="row.entity.taskLinkRowConfig" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
            <span ng-class="{'action-link-disable':taskmanagerlink.disableLinkForIWF(rowItem),'action-link':!taskmanagerlink.disableLinkForIWF(rowItem)}" ng-click="taskmanagerlink.disableLinkForIWF(rowItem) || taskmanagerlink.onItemClick(rowItem)" class="ng-binding action-link" role="button" tabindex="0">21944 GSA latest</span>
            <span class="ng-binding">Testing Sub Category</span>
        </wcl-task-manager-link-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Xpath code

```
//span[text()="21944 GSA latest"]
```

Comment: i got it working. thanks guys! //span[text()="21944 GSA latest"]/preceding::div/input

Comment: Shouldn't `//span[text()="21944 GSA latest"]/preceding::input`also work?